# Java and substring

Tags: java, substring

I need something simmilar to "awk { print $1 }", but for java. I have a string, similar to this:

word1 word2 word3
word4 word5 word6

How, can I substring first word, from every line?

Answer (score 9):

```
String example = "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6";
String firstWord = example.split(" ", 2)[0];
```

Comment: Just be sure that list isn't empty as you go through the data. :)

Comment: Using split(" ", 1) would be better. It reduces the number of unnecessary strings created to only one unnecessary string instead of lots.

Comment: Oops should be 2 sorry. "The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times" from http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: I fixed it for you, seeing as it was my fault!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that doesn't fail if there is only one word on the line. I assume that you have already stripped the new line characters, and that space is the only allowed separator:

```
    for (String line: lines)
    {
        int index = line.indexOf(' ');
        String firstWord;
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            firstWord = line.substring(0, index);
        }
        else
        {
            firstWord = line;
        }
        System.out.println(firstWord);
    }
```

Comment: my solution doesn't fail if there is only one word...if split() cannot find the separator, it just keeps the string in the first element of the array.

Comment: My solution doesn't fail either. Plus it uses much less memory and it doesn't scan the entire string. You should at least add the optimization I suggested as a comment to your answer.

Comment: done, thanks (I was just answering the "here is a solution that doesn't fail...")

Answer (score 3):

```
String example = "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6";
int indexOf = example.indexOf(" ");
String firstWord = example.substring(0, indexOf == -1? example.length: indexOf);
```

Comment: This fails if the line only has one word.

Comment: Now it'll give you an empty string if you've only got one word.